# How to add a variable to a loop?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
  smoke <- matrix(c(51,43,22,92,28,21,68,22,9),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
  colnames(smoke) <- c("High","Low","Middle")
  smoke=as.data.frame(smoke);smoke$sit[1]="bit"; smoke$sit[2]="bsa"
  smoke$sit[3]="bu"
    smoke
      High Low Middle sit
   1   51  43     22 bit
   2   92  28     21 bsa
   3   68  22      9  bu
```

I want apply my simple function:

```
    myf<- function(c,r){
    x=5*c+r
    write.table(x,paste0("res_", r, "_", c, ".txt"))}
    res=apply(smoke[,c('Low','High')], 1, function(x) myf(x[1],x[2]))
```

This works fine.output  `res_51_43.txt .......`

Now I just want to add the corresponding names from `smoke$sit` to output text files. desired output  `res_bit_51_43.txt .......`

```
    myf<- function(t,c,r){x=5*c+r
    write.table(x,paste0("res_", t, r, "_", c, ".txt"))}
   res=apply(smoke[,c('Low','High','sit')], 1, function(x) myf(x[1],x[2],x[3]))
```

I got this error:

```
              Error in 5 * c : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: apply converts your data to matrix, and hence your variables to character (as matrices can only hold one data-type). And you would help yourself if you used more descriptive variable names in your function argument.

Comment: You could use lapply on a split dataframe (list can have multiple data-types in them)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using lapply and split. Note: I've modified your function to return a filename.

```
myf<- function(c,r,t){
  x=5*c+r
  myfile <- paste0("res_", t, r, "_", c, ".txt")
  return(myfile)
}

res=lapply(split(smoke[,c('Low','High','sit')],1:nrow(smoke)), 
    FUN=function(x) myf(c=x[1],r=x[2],t=x[3]))
> res
$`1`
[1] "res_bit51_43.txt"

$`2`
[1] "res_bsa92_28.txt"

$`3`
[1] "res_bu68_22.txt"
```

Comment: I'm not generating text files on my machine. What about the provided code is giving you problems?

Comment: Yes It worked but in the output text file, it does not return '`x`(the name I provided)'. `'my function: "x"
"Low" 266'`______`'yourfunction :"Low" "1" 266'`

Comment: I couldn't really figure out your variable mappings, as you switch them around a lot. The issue of generating filenames and the error you got using 'apply' seems solved to me. Maybe try myf(c=x[2], r=x[1], t=x[3]) inside function(x)?